# How to calc the sum of consecutive columns until a custom date

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I have a table that stores all the info about our contacts, including the day they registered in our website.

I need to have the sum of all of those registrations until a given time (ex. Sum of all registrations until November 2022). I am able to extract the registrations of a specific time, but not *until* that month.

I tried this

```
select count(*) as registrations,
to_char(registration_at::date, 'Month')  as reg_month,
extract(month from registration_at) as reg_month_num,
extract(year from registration_at) as reg_year
from my_table
where registration_at > DATEADD(month, -6, GetDate())
group by 2,3,4
```

The output is something like this:

| Registrations | reg_month | reg_month_num | reg_year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | November | 11 | 2022 |
| 15000 | December | 12 | 2022 |

But I'd need something like this

| Registrations | reg_month | reg_month_num | reg_year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | until_november | 11 | 2022 |
| 15000 | until_december | 12 | 2022 |

And by "until_month" I mean: all registrations from day 0 to the selected month.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions to generate the running count - but this requires doing the work over the whole table before it can be filtered.

Here is one approach:

```
select monthly_count, running_count,
    to_char(registration_at, 'Month')  as reg_month,
    extract(month from registration_at) as reg_month_num,
    extract(year from registration_at) as reg_year
from (
    select date_trunc('month', registration_at) as registration_at,
        count(*) as monthly_count
        sum(count(*)) (over order by date_trunc('month', registration_at)) as running_count
    from mytable
    group by 1
) t 
where registration_at > dateadd(month, -6, date_trunc('month', current_date))
```

This gives you the counts and running counts for the last (entire) 6 months of data; the subquery works over the whole table to compute the running counts, then the outer query filters.

Comment: Thank you so much! I did some small changes here:

'sum(count(*)) over (partition by country order by date_trunc('month', registration_at)'

and it worked! Thank you so much, @gmb